# What term is rounded in the CUDA __fsqrt round intrinsics?

Tags: cuda

I need the square root of a float, in CUDA device code.  Hard to say whether speed matters more than accuracy in my use case.

[__sqrtf CUDA intrinsic is the natural choice](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__SINGLE.html#group__CUDA__MATH__SINGLE_1gcb80df3c252b3feb3cc88f992b955a14)

But then I saw the [various __fsqrt with rounding CUDA intrinsics](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__SINGLE.html#group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__SINGLE_1gf021e85b5e9de141a0fc2ff6fbe85875);

What is rounded in these intrinsics; the argument "x" or the return value?  Or do I misunderstand the meaning of rounding here?

My testing suggests neither is rounded!  I wrote a kernel that evaluates:

```
__fsqrt_rn(42 * 42 + 0.1)
```

and the return value is always 42.0011902, which is equal to the square root of 42 * 42 + 0.1.  So what is being rounded?

Comment: BTW Other ways to 'calculate' the sqrt would be a) a look-up table in memory, optionally with interpolation between two values with texture access or 'manually' with floating point calculations; depending on the stretch of the values those accesses would be cached; or b) by using approximation formulas. sqrt(42*42+.1)≈42+.1/(2*42)=42.00119048

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a rounding mode for the result.  Input arguments are not "rounded" before they are injected into the arithmetic flow.

the "rn" rounding "direction" is "round-to-nearest"

It means that at whatever precision the interim result is being calculated to, that result will be rounded to the nearest available representation.  In the case of a `float` final result, it will be rounded to the nearest available `float` representation.

Let's revisit your example.  When I put your problem into the windows 10 calculator, the result I get is 42.001190459319126303634970957554    The way we get from that "correct result at arbitrary precision" to a 32-bit floating point "rn" result is to take the two 32-bit floating point numbers, one which is closest but numerically higher, and one which is closest but numerically lower, and of those 2, select the one that is closest.  That is apparently 42.0011902.